# how to add title to jquery news ticker?

Tags: jquery, ticker

I am working on Jquery news ticker plugin. I want to add Title to my News, like "latest news" and i want to append "Read More" with every news. just like example here:

```
            [http://www.mubadala.com/en/who-we-are][1]
```

So far, i have this as u can check from this example on jsfiddle:

```
              [http://jsfiddle.net/ezEtK/252/][2]
```

I have tried adding title tag, but i am at loss what to do?

im kindda new to jquery, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do. add anchor tag with class which has css float right. Check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezEtK/254/

Added the latest news link too.

Example:

```
.read{
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i see the title, but "read more" link as u have added in the code, doesnt show up?

Comment: doesn't show up in the fiddle ? Which browser are you using ?..I can see it...extreme right...it's kinda overflowing on "result" - text of fiddle

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thanks once again!